# How can i use certificate based authentication for SQL using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

i want to do **certificate based authentication for SQL** using powershell.

My current code is below for building connection with database:

```
##SQL PART
$connString = "Data Source=$SqlServer;Database=$Database;User ID=$SqlAuthLogin;Password=$SqlAuthPw"
        
#Create a SQL connection object
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString
        
#Attempt to open the connection
$conn.Open()
```

I can't use any other ways to pass password as there are some limitations.

As I'm new to this what further steps should I take to do certificate based authentication will really be helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use integrated security?

Comment: The scenarios where (on-prem) SQL Server supports certificate-based authentication are limited to machine-to-machine communication. You cannot use a client certificate mapped to a user to log in to SQL Server (this role is mostly taken up by integrated security). Azure SQL does support certificate-based authentication, but this mechanism goes through Azure AD and is quite different ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication)).

Comment: Authentication usually refers to a client server HTTP/HTTPS connection.  SQL Server either uses Windows Credentials or SQL Credentials (username and password).  Certificates are normally used with a HTTPS using TLS.  It is not clear where you need to use a certificate.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for reply , but instead of passing password in connection string i want to use certificate for that. Is it possible to do so.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks for reply , my sql server is on prem server and i want to pass password through certificates instead of some encryption or plain text , is it possible to do so.

Comment: SQL Server only has two modes 1) Windows Credentials 2) Username Password.  Windows Credentials uses the user account information.  The connection to SQL can be TLS which uses a certificate.  You can do following : 1. Create/obtain a TLS certificate
2. Install ('provision') that TLS certificate onto the SQL server
3. Start menu, launch: SQL Server Configuration Manager
4. Expand SQL Server Network Configuration
5. Right-click Protocols for <server instance>,and then select Properties:
6. On the Certificate tab, select the desired certificate from the Certificate drop-down menu, click OK:

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for reply , after adding certificate in sql server, what changes should i make on script for connection string to get connected to SQL server as SQL is hosted on another onprem.

Comment: The certificate I assume is on local machine in your stores.  So TLS will check stores.  Then you just need to change connection string and remove ID and Password and instead useintegrated security = true.

Comment: _I want to pass password through certificates instead of some encryption or plain text , is it possible to do so_ No. That's not how it works with on prem SQL. You need to read and understand what windows authentication is.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for reply, As i'm new to this so a bit confuse that certificate will be at all local machines and same certificate will be configured in SQL server on another on prem . Is this what you are saying or something else. Then on script I will do integrated security = true

Comment: HTTPS (secure uses TLS with certificate) in latest versions of Net/Core is done using the OS and is performed before the HTTP request is sent.  The server sends a certificate block with the names of possible certificates to use.  The client looks up the certificate names in the stores and locates a matching certificate name.  The same certificate can be loaded on many clients.  When SQL server is installed it defaults to a window credential for database which is a user group account(not user name and password).  It also sets up an admin account which uses a password.